# Issues with mesa driver after update

Tags: drivers, xorg, opengl, amdgpu, mesa

## Issue

Some graphical applications will return this error in the terminal and refuse to run. This issue appeared after a recent update and upgrade

```
DRI driver not from this Mesa build ('23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2' vs '24.1~git2403020600.63d2aa~oibaf~j (git-63d2aa4 2024-03-02 jammy-oibaf-ppa)')
failed to load driver: radeonsi
DRI driver not from this Mesa build ('23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2' vs '24.1~git2403020600.63d2aa~oibaf~j (git-63d2aa4 2024-03-02 jammy-oibaf-ppa)')
failed to load driver: radeonsi
DRI driver not from this Mesa build ('23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2' vs '24.1~git2403020600.63d2aa~oibaf~j (git-63d2aa4 2024-03-02 jammy-oibaf-ppa)')
DRI driver not from this Mesa build ('23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2' vs '24.1~git2403020600.63d2aa~oibaf~j (git-63d2aa4 2024-03-02 jammy-oibaf-ppa)')
failed to load driver: radeonsi
DRI driver not from this Mesa build ('23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2' vs '24.1~git2403020600.63d2aa~oibaf~j (git-63d2aa4 2024-03-02 jammy-oibaf-ppa)')
failed to load driver: radeonsi
DRI driver not from this Mesa build ('23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2' vs '24.1~git2403020600.63d2aa~oibaf~j (git-63d2aa4 2024-03-02 jammy-oibaf-ppa)')
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  130
  Current serial number in output stream:  131
```

**Kernel**: 5.15.0-92-generic

**WM**: dwm

**window system display server**: x11/xorg

I am using the kernals amggpu driver

output of `lshw -c video`

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: c4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:42 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:d0500000-d057ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

output of `lspci -k | grep -A 3 -E "(VGA|3D)"`

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c4)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Picasso
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

output of `inxi -G`

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Mobile Series]
    driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Device-2: Chicony Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu gpu: amdgpu
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: N/A v: N/A
```

I'm assuming that this is happening because I have no renderer for OpenGL

## Things I've tried

- Installing the latest stable version of Mesa driver
- Using `amd-install` command to install the amd gpu stack
- Uninstalling and reinstalling x11, xorg, and xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
- Installing freeglut3-dev (OpenGL)

I've since removed the removed the ppa for the latest version of the mesa driver because that did not fix the issue. I also removed `amdgpu-install` because installing the amd gpu stack did not fix the issue either.

When I installed the amd gpu stack some graphical applications like glxinfo (but not my window manager dwm) would return a segfault

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still have a mix of files from different Mesa versions as "DRI driver not from this Mesa build" is telling you. Let's remove the conflicting packages.

Normally, you would use [`ppa-purge`](https://askubuntu.com/a/310/1004020) as [the PPA itself recommends](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers):

```bash
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

If that doesn't work, we can target the package containing `dpkg -S radeonsi` specifically:

```bash
sudo dpkg --force-all -P libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 mesa-opencl-icd:amd64
sudo apt install -f
```

Removing the PPA does not remove the installed packages, so you have to remove the packages separately. At least parts of `amdgpu-install` are related to the kernel driver, while the problem here is the userspace driver.

Oibaf replied to my email. For bug reports, please use the bug tracker links and not emails.

> About ppa-purge not working: make sure to have the ppa enabled before
> purging (otherwise ppa-purge doesn't know which are the packages to
> revert).

Comment: Stange `sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers` fixed the issue. I remember doing that before and it didn't work.

Comment: There is now another question about oibaf at https://askubuntu.com/q/1506318/1004020 , so I sent an email on Launchpad