# 23.10 Folder "Properties" icons look like colorful static after installing oibaf/graphics-drivers

Tags: graphics, icons, ppa, 23.10

I'm running 23.10 and just noticed that if I right click a folder, file, or shortcut from file browser and select properties the icon looks like static. How do I fix these broken icons?

- Graphics Card: AMD Radeon RX 7600 (RADV NAVI33)
- Graphics Driver: radv
- Driver Version: Mesa 24.1~git2402290600.3d38c9~oibaf~m (git-3d38c95
  2024-02-29 mantic-oibaf-ppa)

[image]

```
lspci ; LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 nautilus

00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:05.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. Device 5017 (rev 03)
02:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 500 Series Chipset USB 3.1 XHCI Controller
02:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 500 Series Chipset SATA Controller
02:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 500 Series Chipset Switch Upstream Port
03:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Upstream Port of PCI Express Switch (rev 12)
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Downstream Port of PCI Express Switch (rev 12)
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 33 [Radeon RX 7700S/7600/7600S/7600M XT/PRO W7600] (rev cf)
07:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 31 HDMI/DP Audio
08:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
09:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
09:00.1 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP
09:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
09:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
** Message: 17:13:31.040: Connecting to org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files
```

Comment: What do you get from `lspci ; LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 nautilus` ? Does it happen with a new user?

Comment: @DanielT question updated with requested info

Comment: Does problem go away if you put a document into the empty `Documents` folder?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Nope. Adding a file to the folder changes nothing. The icon looks like this for any file/folder I try to view the properties for.

Comment: Did LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE fix the icon? Does creating a new user or deleting `~/.cache` and `~/.local/share/icons` help?

Comment: Also what if you go to `gnome-tweaks` > Appearance > Icons and set it to something else?

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte Adding a file to `Documents` must change the string that says ***Empty folder*** though?

Comment: @DanielT LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE did not fix it. I can't just delete all of .cache because I have like 12 gigs of processed shaders in there for gaming.. I tried deleting .cache/thumbnails to no avail. I deleted .local/share/icons and that didn't work either. haven't tried creating a new user yet... looking at gnome-tweaks now

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yes, it says "1 File"

Comment: @DanielT added a new user "test", same problem when logged in as "test" user

Comment: @DanielT ok, we are making progress! The issue is with the Yaru icons. All other icon sets work fine. I tried `sudo apt install --reinstall yaru-theme-icon` but the problem persists.

Comment: Check with a 23.10 LiveCD, or after downgrading Mesa back to stable

Comment: You can also try `find /usr/share/icons -name '*.cache' -exec echo rm {} +` , then copy that command and run it with `sudo`

Comment: OMG! it was the stupid oibaf drivers that I thought was a good idea to install... NOPE... ppa-purge wouldn't fix it and I had to follow the instructions here: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=381601 I will add an answer now

Comment: You can see my answer today at https://askubuntu.com/a/1506304/1004020 if my second suggestion with `dpkg --force-all -P <something>`

Comment: Nice. Your answer seem to more comprehensively cover packages in comparison to mine. If you're looking for the latest Mesa, I personally use kisak-mesa, which is from Valve

Answer (score 2):

The issues I had were with the drivers from the oibaf PPA. Here's how I fixed it:

1. Revert to stable drivers

Using the command suggested by the PPA maintainer `sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`  didn't work, nor did attempting to specify my distro with `sudo ppa-purge -d mantic ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`. I had to follow the instructions from https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=381601 which are (more or less) as follows:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo dpkg -P --force-depends libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-common libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libegl-mesa0 libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0 libxatracker2 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

And reboot your computer.

2. If you are using Steam you will need to reinstall it.

```
sudo apt remove steam-launcher steam-libs-amd64
```

Download the Steam installer from steampowered.com to your ~/Downloads folder (if you don't already have it) then:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
```

Then run steam to install as normal. Do not install Steam from Snap or App Center as it doesn't work right. You need to install the Steam .deb package downloaded from steampowered.com

Comment: That's the wrong syntax for `ppa-purge`.  It's just, for example, `sudo ppa-purge ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next`. No `-d mantic`

Comment: actually it's not the incorrect syntax... you can go without the -d switch and it still doesn't work. -d mantic is SUPPOSED to tell it what repo to revert to... neither work... you can try ppa-purge -h to learn more... using the -d switch made it SAY it was doing the right thing, but still, nothing actually happened. without the -d switch it said it was reverting to itself

Comment: I've used ppa-purge successfully plenty of times, I don't need to learn more.

Comment: that's great that it worked for you. didn't work for me. try installing the oibaf PPA and see if you can get rid of it with ppa-purge

Comment: Oibaf replied about ppa-purge: https://askubuntu.com/posts/1506304/revisions

Comment: @DanielT I think it's something with ppa-purge because when I ran it not only did it leave all the oibaf drivers in place it didn't remove or disable the ppa either. I made sure the PPA was enabled before running ppa-purge, that wasn't the issue. Looking for the answer I found a lot of people having this issue. It looks like a really old program... perhaps that's the issue.